# COMMIT errored in a shell script

Tags: neo4j

I started a Neo4J shell script on Linux with at Begin command, created 3500 relationships and ended it with COMMIT: the commit errored and said it was not a valid command, I'm assuming because of the ; and the end of the commit... How do I know if the transaction rolled back or how can I roll it back?

Answer (score 3):

Don't completely understand your question. `begin`/`commit`/`rollback` do not need a trailing semicolon, but cypher statements used in neo4j-shell do. See the following transscript:

```
$ bin/neo4j-shell
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (0)$ begin
Transaction started
neo4j-sh (0)$ create (:Person {name:'John'});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1    
4 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ rollback
Transaction rolled back
neo4j-sh (0)$ begin
Transaction started
neo4j-sh (0)$ create (:Person {name:'John'});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
9 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ commit
Transaction committed
```

rollback and commit give very clear messages, either "Transaction rolled back" or "Transaction committed". If you leave a shell session which contains a `begin` but does not finish with `commit` nor with `rollback` the transaction is rolled back on shell termination.